# Search all rows of sheet for value and format entire row

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to:

1. Search the sheet for a value
2. Format the entire row in which the value is situated

The following code finds "Apple", but does not continue to search the sheet.

I assume I need a For Next. I can't specify the column to search because it could vary.

```vb
Dim Fruit As Range
Set Fruit = Cells.Find(what:="Apple", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not Fruit Is Nothing Then
    If Fruit.Row <> Fruit Then
    Fruit.EntireRow.Select
    End If
End If

Selection.Font.Italic = True
With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0.4
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
    Dim Fruit As Range
Set Fruit = Cells.Find(what:="Apple")
Do While Fruit.Cells.Font.Italic = False
    Fruit.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Font.Italic = True
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0.4
    End With
    Set Fruit = Cells.Find(after:=Fruit.Cells, what:="Apple", LookAt:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext)
Loop
```

I don't think its the optimal solution, but it seems to get the job done.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! I was so stuck on trying to get "For Next" to work that I hadn't realised there was a "Loop" option. Much appreciated.